# Related to Thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

1. One mole of an ideal gas at 300K is expanded isothermally from one litre volume to ten litres of volume. Find change in internal energy in this process? R= 2cal/K/mol.
2. Calculate the work done when one mole of gas expands reversible isothermally from 5 atm to 1 atm at 300K? (value of log5= 0.6989)

Comment: PLease read the posting guidelines.  This is not a "do your homework for you" site.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1.

As its isothermal so the temperature remains constant. So the change in internal energy is 0.

Answer 2.

Its formula is $W = -nRT$ $log_e(P_i/P_f)$

Putting the values we get $W = -4012.6497831$

Here $W$ is work done on the system